# jQuery while loop makes browser crash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following while loop in my webpage:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $("#quote").height();
    //alert("Toegestane hoogte: 500px\nHuidige hoogte: "+height+"px");
    while (height > 500) {
        var fontSize = $('p', $('#quote')).css('font-size').split('px')[0];
        var fontInt = parseInt(fontSize) - 1;
        fontInt = fontInt + 'px';
        $('p', $('#quote')).css('font-size', fontInt);
    }
});
```

Somehow, when I load the page, the browser keeps loading and eventually it crashes...

Comment: You must update the height **in** the loop. How is that loop supposed to halt ?

Comment: @dystroy you should post that as answer

Comment: Use if instead of while in the code. I think if(height > 500) will do the work

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida I think the OP is trying to decrease the font size until the container is < 500px.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox if that is the case then ur suggestion is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var `height` is never increased during the loop, which causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The var `height` is never increased in your loop resulting  into an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Check using if statement

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $("#quote").height();
    //alert("Toegestane hoogte: 500px\nHuidige hoogte: "+height+"px");
    if (height > 500) {
        var fontSize = $('p', $('#quote')).css('font-size').split('px')[0];
        var fontInt = parseInt(fontSize) - 1;
        fontInt = fontInt + 'px';
        $('p', $('#quote')).css('font-size', fontInt);
    }
});
```

Or Do operation with height,Increase or decrease